# Sbt task for picocli graalvm reflection generation?

Tags: scala, sbt, graalvm, picocli

In picocli they give examples on [how](https://github.com/remkop/picocli/blob/master/picocli-codegen/README.md) to generate GraalVM reflection configurations during the build for Maven and Gradle.

#### Gradle example

```
configurations {
    generateConfig
}
dependencies {
    compile 'info.picocli:picocli:3.9.3'
    generateConfig 'info.picocli:picocli-codegen:3.9.3'
}
```

task

```
task(generateGraalReflectionConfig, dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'picocli.codegen.aot.graalvm.ReflectionConfigGenerator'
    classpath = configurations.generateConfig + sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    def outputFile = new File(project.buildDir, 'cli-reflect.json')
    args = ["--output=$outputFile", 'com.your.package.YourCommand1', 'com.your.package.YourCommand2']
}
assemble.dependsOn generateGraalReflectionConfig
```

How could I write something equivalent for sbt ?

This is what I got so far but I don't know if I'm going in the right direction.

```scala
import Dependencies._

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.8"
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
ThisBuild / organization := "com.example"
ThisBuild / organizationName := "example"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "poc-cli",
    libraryDependencies += scalaTest % Test,
    libraryDependencies += "info.picocli" % "picocli" % "3.9.3",
    libraryDependencies += "info.picocli" % "picocli-codegen" % "3.9.3",
  )

lazy val graalConfig = inputKey[Unit]("gen-graal-config") 

graalConfig:= {
    val conf = (runMain in Compile).fullInput(" picocli.codegen.aot.graalvm.ReflectionConfigGenerator --output=cli-reflect.json example.Hello").evaluated
}

enablePlugins(GraalVMNativeImagePlugin)
```

#### Edit

in my initial question, I had the code below, with my current code the problem is solved

```
lazy val graalConfig = taskKey[Unit]("graal-config") := {
    Process("java" :: "-jar" :: "picocli.codegen.aot.graalvm.ReflectionConfigGenerator" :: "--output" :: "cli-reflect.json" :: "???" :: Nil,
        baseDirectory.value / "lib").!
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was

```
import Dependencies._


ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.8"
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
ThisBuild / organization := "com.example"
ThisBuild / organizationName := "example"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "poc-cli",
    libraryDependencies += scalaTest % Test,
    libraryDependencies += "info.picocli" % "picocli" % "3.9.3",
    libraryDependencies += "info.picocli" % "picocli-codegen" % "3.9.3",
  )

lazy val graalConfig = inputKey[Unit]("gen-graal-config")

graalVMNativeImageOptions += "-H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=../cli-reflect.json"

graalConfig:= {
    (runMain in Compile).fullInput(" picocli.codegen.aot.graalvm.ReflectionConfigGenerator -o=target/cli-reflect.json example.Hello").evaluated
}

enablePlugins(GraalVMNativeImagePlugin)
```

then I can run:

```
$ sbt graalConfig
$ sbt graalvm-native-image:packageBin
```

Answer (score 2):

picocli-codegen fixes picocli project reflections.

There is [Graal Reflection Configuration Generator](https://github.com/mageddo-projects/graal-reflection-configuration-generator) which generates the `reflection.json` automatically for me and attach it in the resulting **jar** just by adding it to my dependencies as **AnnotationProcessor** and annotating the classes, **package scan** is also supported.

This way you can easily generate reflection config whenever you needs it. Snippet example of how to configure and use it.

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  compileOnly("com.mageddo.nativeimage:reflection-config-generator:2.1.1")
  annotationProcessor("com.mageddo.nativeimage:reflection-config-generator:2.1.1")
}
```

Config.java

```
@Reflection(declaredConstructors = true, scanPackage = "com.github.vo")
public class Config {}
```

Maven, and vanilla java are also supported, for more details check [GRCG docs](https://github.com/mageddo-projects/graal-reflection-configuration-generator), check also [this article](http://bookmarks.mageddo.com/bookmark/634/Automatically-configure-native-image-reflection-configuration) talking about this tool

Comment: The link to the [article](http://bookmarks.mageddo.com/bookmark/634/Automatically-configure-native-image-reflection-configuration) is not accessible without a login...

Comment: @RemkoPopma Thanks for the warning, it is working right now